# How to manage Scopes according to the User and not the Client?

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, server

I've been following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server) tutorial in order to create an Authentication Server, but I'm facing some problems regarding the concepts, I guess.

Look, when I register a Client in Repository, I have to define some parameters, like its id, secret, authentication method, grant types, redirection uris and scopes:

```
@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId("articles-client")
            .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/articles-client-oidc")
            .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
            .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
            .scope("articles.read")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
}
```

When I'm back to my Resource Server, I find that my client was successfully logged in and it returns with an "articles.read" scope. Everything is fine here, supposing that I want to protect my endpoints with the Client's scope, but this is not my case.

In my situation, I want to protect my endpoints according to my User's role in database.

I'll give you an example, so you don't have to read the whole Baeldung's website:

1. I try to access: http://localhost:8080/articles.
2. It redirects to: http://auth-server:9000, where a Spring Security Login Form appears.
3. When you submit the proper credentials (which are compared from a database using the default Spring Security schema), it basically gets you back to: http://localhost:8080/articles.

Well, in that point, I have an Authorization Token with the Client scope, but not the logged User role.

Is there an standard way to configure my project to achieve this or, do I have to think of a creative way to do so?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For role based authentication you should map authorities in Oauth token.
`OAuth2AuthenticationToken.getAuthorities()` is used for authorizing requests, such as in `hasRole('USER')` or `hasRole('ADMIN')`.

For this you need to implement the `userAuthoritiesMapper`, something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().userAuthoritiesMapper(this.userAuthoritiesMapper());
        //.oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService());
        super.configure(http);
    }

    private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities) -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(authority -> {
                if (OidcUserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    OidcUserAuthority oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority)authority;

                    OidcUserInfo userInfo = oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo();
                    if (userInfo.containsClaim("role")){
                        String roleName = "ROLE_" + userInfo.getClaimAsString("role");
                        mappedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleName));
                    }
                } else if (OAuth2UserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    OAuth2UserAuthority oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority)authority;
                    Map<String, Object> userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();
                    
                    if (userAttributes.containsKey("role")){
                        String roleName = "ROLE_" + (String)userAttributes.get("role");
                        mappedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleName));
                    }
                }
            });

            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a configuration for the Authorization or the Resource Server? As far as I understand, it is for the first one but, what if I'm not using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but SecurityFilterChain, as in the tutorial?

Comment: this is the configuration for Authorization server. You can easily configure your SecurityFilterChange using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Roles will come from your UserDetailsService.